# how to find if the same matrix has one solution, infinitely many solutions and no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The matrix is as follows:
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
      a&0&b&2\\
      a&a&4&4\\
0&a&2&b
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I need to find when this matrix will have one, infinitely many, and no solutions by expressing condition on a, b and c

I did put the matrix in reduced row echelon form as follow:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
      1&0&0&\frac{2-b}{a}\\
      0&1&0&\frac{b-2}{a}\\
0&0&1&\frac{2-b}{a}
    \end{array}
\right] $$

but now I'm stuck about how to express the conditions on a, b, and c

Comment: It seems you have multiplied some row by $1/a$ at least one time. It is strictly prohibited to do so if $a=0$. Also, at any time during your row operations, see if you are multiplying rows by $0$ - that is also prohibited.

Comment: Oh you right! I didn't notice this, thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduction should have gotten you here:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
      a&0&b&2\\
      0&a&4-b&2\\
0&0&b-2&b-2
    \end{array}
\right] $$

This is far enough to analyze the different cases:

---

- Unique:

We must have a leading term for each column. Therefore, $b \neq 2$ and $a \neq 0$.

---

- No Solutions:

For this to occur we must have a row where the left side is all zeros, but the right side is not. This can occur if:

1. $a = b = 0$
2. $a = 0$ and $b= 4$

---

- Infinitely Many Solutions:

This occurs when we have a free variable. This is achieved by getting a whole row (including the right side) or column to be zeros:

1. $a = 0$
2. $b = 2$